# What is a word for someone who is not the sole decision maker?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a parent can be the decision maker over a child's actions if under the age of 16. They can be a sole decision maker, active in making decisions for the child.

But, what is someone who does not make all the decisions - kind of like a co-parent, but more general. Co-decision-maker. More passive, someone who consults another individual before making the decision or works in harmony with someone rather than taking control and making all the decisions.

Comment: Depends on their motivation. Lacking self confidence, aware of their own limitations, politically astute, lazy, team player. General idea questions are poorly suited for this site. Just give us one concrete sentence that we can supply a term for. If working in harmony is an import motivation, run with that.

Answer (score -1):

A corporate word that fits is **stakeholder**, although it is not strictly related to decision making.

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder_(corporate)) on the topic,

> A stakeholder is a member of groups without whose support [an] organization would cease to exist.

Usually, stakeholders take joint decisions regarding the business or the issue they have a stake in.

Comment: I think of it the other way around.  A stakeholder is someone whose success is directly affected by the product and whose input is therefore sought when creating the product.  They do not necessarily get to vote on how the product is constructed however.

Comment: @Jim *Stakeholder* is a broad umbrella term that covers anybody interested or involved in a company. This includes the owners, investors and shareholders, who would be involved in decision making. I agree that customers, employees and other entities not involved in decision making are also stakeholders, which is why I said that the word is not strictly related to decision making.